# When the credentials (ID and password) managed by IdP was changed, Should the access token stored in RP be issued newly?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I have talked about the specification when the credentials was changed by the Authorization Code Flow of OpenIdConnect or OAuth2.

When the credentials (ID and password) managed by IdP was changed, the access token stored in RP is discarded, and user authentication is required again? Or should it be able to use the access token as it was before the change?

Answer (score 0):

The access token lifecycle is not linked to the user account status.

An access token can still be valid if the resource owner credentials changed or even if it's account has been blocked.

In general, an access token is revoked by the client itself (revocation endpoint) or by the issuer (security policy/compromised token).

Comment: Thanks, What you are saying is certainly correct.  Do you think that it is better to revoke a token before returning a token error with a resource API call on the RP side?